One site is blank in Android Firefox
I just got a new phone, a Pixel 9 Pro XL. Warhorn.net main page loads without CSS, and all the other pages are blank on my phone, even if I request the Desktop site.
This only happens on Firefox on this phone, it works without a problem in Chrome on the same device, and in Firefox on all of my other devices.
All other sites seem to load just fine.
How can I fix this?

If you think this is a bug you should post it into the Mozilla bug tracker for Firefox Android.

I wonder if Firefox has a setting/extension related to privacy that may accidentally block some resources. I often heard about similar issues from Firefox users.

Clearing the cache solved it
I find it really strange, as it never worked on the new phone. I would expect clearing the cache only to work if something gets stuck from a previous load, but here there were no previous.
